# How can I cast the data packet from a websocket which holds a c++ struct

Tags: javascript, c++, struct, casting

I have this struct which is sent to a client using websocket.

```
struct packet
{
    TYPE type;      //4 byte
    int size;       //4 byte
    bool property1; //1 byte
    bool property2; //1 byte 
    bool property3; //1 byte
};
```

The size of the packet is 11 bytes. Is there a way that I could create an object in JS with that structure and cast the data that I'm receiving into that structure? Thanks!

Comment: It's likely that padding will make the object > 11 bytes. Use `sizeof` to check.  Not saying you will sent the raw struct over the network, but just in case

Comment: The struct is always changing and I'd rather not worry about the padding each time I add or remove a member. Even with the padding I'd still have to manually parse it right? Thanks Lwimsey

Comment: Padding is irrelevant as long as you don't wrap the raw struct into a network packet.

Comment: I'm sending that struct over network to a client using javascript websocket. Just trying to find out what's the most convenient way of casting the data sent from the c++ server to a javascript object with similar structure above.